# HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, webrequest, webresponse

I am trying to get the Response string by using C#'s WebRequest and WebResponse classes.

It pulls the string but some part such as forms are missing from response.But when I open the same URL in browser(manually) and inspect elements using firebug it shows every thing.

What may be the problem that I am not getting complete response from WebResponse...???

Comment: How do you get the string? Maybe you have a bug in that code?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons possible (Javascript, IFRAMEs etc.), for example:

IF the site is using AJAX/JavaScript to build those forms dynamically on the client THEN what you see is correct... Background: since WebRequest does not execute Javascript the result "HttpWebRequest" versus Browser is different...

Answer (score 0):

Because WebRequest does not run Javascript code inserted into website. You would have to evaluate javascript by yourself.
Duplicate: [C# httpwebrequest and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516027/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-and-javascript)