# asp.net xmlhttprequest...Ajax Content

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest

I'm using an asp.net c# xmlhttprequest to read an external web page content.
When I'm getting the page content I see only part of the text (content) and not the whole content. Then I did some search and find out that some of the page content is loading with Ajax (after the page is loading) and thats why I cant get it.

i'm using `HttpWebRequest`

My question is: how can i get the whole page content

Comment: What part are you not getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# httpwebrequest and javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516027/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-and-javascript)